# storing output of prime numbers in array and then check for user input in that array

Tags: java

Hi i wrote a program to print first 1000 prime number.Now i dont know how to store all output in array also i want user to give a number, which i want to search through array and check whether it is there or not.

How crack this problem. Its super easy in python.....: )

here is my program

```
public class Primetester 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("The first thousand prime numbers are:\n");
        printPrime(1000);
    }
public static void printPrime(int numberofprime)
{
    int primeperline=10;
    int count=0;
    int num=2;
    while (count<numberofprime)
    {
        if(isPrime(num)){

    count++;
    if(count%primeperline==0)
    {
        System.out.println(num);

    }
    else
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
        num++;
    }
}

public static boolean isPrime(int num)
{
    for(int div=2;div<=num/2;div++){
    if(num%div==0){
    return false;
    }
    }
        return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use an `ArrayList` or a pre-defined Array of size 1000.

ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
```

....

```
if(isPrime(num)){
 primes.add (num);
```

Array

```
boolean nums [] = new boolean [1000];

if(isPrime(num)){
   nums[num] = true;
```